# Angular $scope function replacement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium

For an old angular app (version 1), I was asked to upload some data via it. I used Selenium to execute a javascript script that replaces the Angular app's `$scope upload function` to something I can work with.

ie

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('#somecontroller')).scope().uploadFunc() { ... }
```

Unfortunately, the new function does not have access to the $scope and various local non $scope functions found within that library.

ie.

```
...uploadFunc() {
  localNonScopeFunc // ERROR: localNonScopeFunc not defined
  $scope // ERROR: $scope not defined
}
```

I was able to get access to `$scope` indirectly but I still can't access any local functions.

I'm pretty sure I just need to bind the controller's `this` to `function` to resolve both issues but not sure how...

**How would I bind the replaced `$scope function` to the angular app?**

---

Update 1:

```
// existing library
var someApp= angular.module('wApp', ['oc.lazyLoad', 'lookup','menu','prompt','service']);
someApp.controller('somecontroller', function ($scope, $timeout, $interval, $http, $ocLazyLoad, $rootScope, service)
{
  $scope.uploadFunc = function() {
    $scope.doSomething();
    NonScopeLibraryFunc();
    ...bad blocking code
  };
}
function NonScopeLibraryFunc() {
  ...
}
```

I have to change the uploadFunc code since its blocking functionality. So I try

```
// selenium JavaScriptExecutor
angular.element(document.querySelector('#somecontroller')).scope().uploadFunc = function () { 
  $scope.doSomething(); // Error: $scope not defined
  NonScopeLibraryFunc() // Error: NonScopeLibraryFunc not defined
  ...better non-blocking code
};
```

Neither $scope or NonScopeLibraryFunc() can be used. I was able to indirectly use $scope but calling NonScopeLibraryFunc is still a no go.

I also tried binding

```
const s = angular.element(document.querySelector('#somecontroller')).scope();
const newUploadFunc = function () { 
  $scope.doSomething(); // Error: $scope not defined
  NonScopeLibraryFunc() // Error: NonScopeLibraryFunc not defined
  ...better non-blocking code
}.bind(s);
s.uploadFunc = newUploadFunc;
```

But it also does work.

Answer (score 0):

Following example of overloading an angular scope function should give you the basics of what you need.

Where you might run into issues is with any arguments that might be passed into the scope function from the view

```js
// Non angular code
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const someVar = 'Local var text';
  // get angular scope
  const angScope = angular.element(document.querySelector('#ang-app')).scope()  
  console.log('Remote access $scope.txt = ', angScope.txt);

  // store reference to original scope function
  const oldFunc = angScope.func
  // overload original function
  angScope.func = function(){     
     // modify scope variable with local value
     angScope.txt = someVar;
     // call original scope function
     oldFunc();
     // if modifying the original scope that needs to be changed in view use $.apply()
     angScope.$apply()
  }  
  angScope.func();  

});

// Angular app
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('main', function($scope) {
    $scope.txt = 'Scope text';
    $scope.func = function(){
       console.log('controller func() called')
       $scope.log()
    }
    
    $scope.log = function(){
        console.log('Scope txt:', $scope.txt);    
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<button>Trigger modified scope func</button>

<div id="ang-app" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="main">
 Angular display: {{txt}}

</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm modifying the function itself. I can't use the existing library's function with its current implementation at all due to its blocking nature. I have no issues modifying and applying other variables or calling other scope functions.

Comment: I went a head and update my question with an explicit example.

Comment: My guess is that `NonScopeLibraryFunc` is defined in an IIFE making it unreachable in the new calling context. Accessing the scope functions is not a problem. In my example you could add `angScope.log()` in the new function and it would work. Do you control the code for this angular app?

Comment: Unfortunately not.